# Is there a command to get builtin commands on zsh?

Tags: zsh, shell-builtin, compgen

Is there a command to get builtin commands on zsh? For example, it is possible to get all builtin commands with the `compgen -b` command in the bash shell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `info zsh builtins`:

> `builtins`
> This associative array gives information about the builtin commands
> currently enabled.  The keys are the names of the builtin commands
> and the values are either 'undefined' for builtin commands that
> will automatically be loaded from a module if invoked or 'defined'
> for builtin commands that are already loaded.

But note that new builtins are made available when you load more modules with `zmodload`.

To `print` the list (the `k`eys of that associative array) `r`aw and `o`rdered on `1` `C`olumn:

```
print -roC1 -- ${(k)builtins}
```

Or you can print the key and values on two columns to see which ones are already loaded and which ones would be automatically loaded upon first invocation:

```
print -raC2 -- ${(kv)builtins} | sort
```

To list all commands and reserved words along with their type, see also:

```
whence -wm '*'
```